# Necesito hacer un insert a 2 tablas relacionadas en laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Así tengo mi controlador

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $marca = MarcaAuto::create(['marca' => $request->marca ]);

        ModeloAuto::create([
            'modelo_auto' => $request->modelo,
            'year_model' => $request->year,
            'marca_auto_id' => $marca->id(),
]);
```

Modelo de `MarcaAuto` (tabla1)

```
class MarcaAuto extends Model
{
   protected $table ='marca_auto';

   protected $fillable = ['marca'];

   public $timestamps = false;

    public function modelo_auto()
   {
         return $this->hasMany(ModeloAuto::class);
   }
}
```

Modelo de ModeloAuto (Tabla2)

```
class ModeloAuto extends Model
{
  protected $table ='';

   protected $fillable = [
              'modelo_auto',
              'year_model',
              'marca_auto_id'];

   public $timestamps = false;

   public function modelo_parte_motor()
   {

        return $this->hasMany(ModeloParteMotor::class);
   }

   public function marca_auto()
    {

        return $this->belongsTo(MarcaAuto::class);
    }
}
```

Este es el error que me da:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::id()

Comment: me da este error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::id()

Answer (score 1):

En el modelo `ModeloAuto` te falta especificar el nombre de la tabla.

`protected $table = '`**modelo_auto**`';`
También podés especificar el `foreign_key` en la relación belongsTo()

```
class ModeloAuto extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'modelo_auto';

   protected $fillable = [
              'modelo_auto',
              'year_model',
              'marca_auto_id'];

   public $timestamps = false;

   public function modelo_parte_motor()
   {

        return $this->hasMany(ModeloParteMotor::class);
   }

   public function marca_auto()
    {

        return $this->belongsTo(MarcaAuto::class, 'marca_auto_id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

primero inserta en uno y utiliza get Last Insert Id para que te de el id de la relacion

$id = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();
te da el id que se inserto

Answer (score 1):

Hay algo que no me queda claro en tu codigo de metodo store()

public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $marca = MarcaAuto::create(['marca' => $request->marca ]);

```
    ModeloAuto::create([
        'modelo_auto' => $request->modelo,
        'year_model' => $request->year,
        'marca_auto_id' => $marca->id(),
```

]);

**1)** Abajo cuando haces: `$marca->id()` pidiendo el valor de un atributo pero no veo la consulta por ninguna parte, tambien debes quitar los parentesis

**2)** Para recibir los datos del request, yo prefiero usar: $request->input('year'),

**3)** El controlador al estar usando varios modelos supongo que lo has declarado previamente en la cabecera. por ejemplo:

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use app\MarcaAuto;
use app\ModeloAuto;

**4)** Tambien como dice la compañera debes colocar el nombre de la tabla porque no estas usando las convenciones de nombre Laravel en el metodo ModeloAuto;

```
protected $table = 'modelo_auto';
```

**5)** Al no usar las convenciones Laravel deberias declarar todos los datos involucrados al hacer la relacion uno a muchos.

**Explicacion:**

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

El  modelo  va a contener un método donde se colocara el siguiente código:

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\Post', 'foreign_key', 'other_key');
```

**Donde:**

**'foreign_key'**  es opcional y se emplea cuando el nombre de la llave foranea es personalizada y no corresponde con la convencion de Laravel.
, '**other_key'** es la llave local primaria que vincula al primer modelo con el Segundo y tambien su uso es opcional cuando se emplea un nombre fuera de la convención.

**6)** Te recomiendo ir probando el codigo de registro para agregar los datos desde tinker. desde alli vas experimentando de formar rapida el comportamiento de tu sintaxis, otra cosa que debes tener en cuenta es reiniciar el tinker cada vez que realices algun cambio en los modelos.

Cosas que deberias probar en el tinker
a) consulta con las relaciones
b) registrar datos en la tabla.